# Restrict ldap and linux users to only use ssh?

Tags: linux, rhel, openldap

I have a RHEL 7 server that we are using as a jumpbox to authenticate to all servers. Typically users will login to jumpserver(rhel 7) from local machine and then login to their respective virtual machines but lately users are storing data on their directory in jumpserver which is very small vm and we don't what users to store any data in-fact i want restrict users to just use it as jumpserver by disabling all others permissions to run any command.

flow: localmachine(open-ldap auth) --> jumpserver-rhel 7(ssh-only) ---> virtual machine

can someone shed some light on how to restrict domain/ldap and linux users to only ssh and do nothing apart from jump to their virtual machine.

Env: everything is rhel 7 based.

Comment: set up disk quota.

Comment: You could also set up their shell to something that doesn’t allowe interactive logins, and force them to use ssh port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how clever your users are you may have to disable SFTP.

For the SSH part: You can

1. set everyone's shell to `rbash`
2. create e.g. `/usr/local/bin/restricted`
3. create a symlink to `ssh` (and maybe other allowed commands) in `/usr/local/bin/restricted`
4. set `$PATH` to `/usr/local/bin/restricted` only in `/etc/profile` / `/etc/bash.bashrc`
5. delete `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` in all home directories (and `/etc/skel`)

Comment: how would that disable to copy files via scp?

Comment: @planetmaker Depends on how `scp` is called on the remote side. If there is no separate method for calling `scp` then it could not be called and thus would fail. I have to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config` with a script which checks whether `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` starts with `ssh` and runs that command line only in that case.

So the users would have to use

```
ssh jumphost ssh realtarget
```

instead of

```
ssh jumphost
```

and running `ssh realtarget` in an interactive shell there.